# I can't insert data into the table due to an SQL error

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-06512, ora-02291

This is the error I get when I insert the data:

```
INSERT INTO "44581114"."TEACHING_INFORMATION" (STAFFID, COURSEID, SEMESTER, YEAR) 
VALUES ('11223344', 'ISYS224', 'S3', '2014')
```

error:

```
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (44581114.FK_TEACHING_RELATIONS_COURSE) violated - parent key not found
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

One error saving changes to table `44581114"."TEACHING_INFORMATION`:
Row 1:

```
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (44581114.FK_TEACHING_RELATIONS_COURSE) violated - parent key not found
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

If it helps i have attached the DDL script here:

```
/*==============================================================*/

/* DBMS name:      ORACLE Version 11g                           */

/* Created on:     11/10/2016 3:47:29 PM                        */
/*==============================================================*/


alter table ACADEMIC_REC
   drop constraint FK_ACADEMIC_RELATIONS_STUDENT;

alter table ACADEMIC_REC
   drop constraint FK_ACADEMIC_RELATIONS_COURSE;

alter table COURSE
   drop constraint FK_COURSE_OFFERS_DEPARTME;

alter table ENROLS
   drop constraint FK_ENROLS_ENROLS_STUDENT;

alter table ENROLS
   drop constraint FK_ENROLS_ENROLS2_TUT_PRAC;

alter table HAS_PREREQUISITE
   drop constraint FK_HAS_PRER_HAS_PRERE_COURSE;

alter table HAS_PREREQUISITE
   drop constraint FK_HAS_PRER_HAS_PRERE_COURSE;

alter table STAFF
   drop constraint FK_STAFF_RELATIONS_DEPARTME;

alter table TEACHING_INFORMATION
   drop constraint FK_TEACHING_RELATIONS_STAFF;

alter table TEACHING_INFORMATION
   drop constraint FK_TEACHING_RELATIONS_COURSE;

alter table TUT_PRAC
   drop constraint FK_TUT_PRAC_HAS_COURSE;

alter table TUT_PRAC
   drop constraint FK_TUT_PRAC_RELATIONS_STAFF;

drop table ACADEMIC_REC  cascade constraints;

drop table COURSE cascade constraints;

drop table ENROLS cascade constraints;

drop table HAS_PREREQUISITE cascade constraints;

drop table STAFF cascade constraints;

drop table STUDENT cascade constraints;

drop table TEACHING_INFORMATION cascade constraints;

drop table TUT_PRAC cascade constraints;


/*==============================================================*/

/* Table: ACADEMIC_REC                                          */

/*==============================================================*/

create table ACADEMIC_REC 

(

 STUID                CHAR(8)              not null,

COURSEID             CHAR(8)              not null,

STATUS               VARCHAR2(5),

YEAR                 NUMBER(4),

SEMESTER             CHAR(2),

 GRADE                VARCHAR2(2)         

constraint CKC_GRADE_ACADEMIC check (GRADE is null or (GRADE in ('HD','D','CR','P','F'))),

constraint PK_ACADEMIC_REC primary key (STUID, COURSEID)
);



/*==============================================================*/

/* Table: COURSE                                                */

/*==============================================================*/

create table COURSE 
(

COURSEID             CHAR(8)              not null,

DEPTID               CHAR(8)              not null,

COURSENAME           VARCHAR2(20),

 TEXTBOOK             VARCHAR2(20),

CREDITHOUR           NUMBER(2),

MAX_ENROL            NUMBER(4),

ACTUAL_ENROL         NUMBER(4),

 AVAILABILITY         NUMBER(4),

 COURSE_TIME          CHAR(7),


constraint PK_COURSE primary key (COURSEID)
);



/*==============================================================*/

/* Table: DEPARTMENT                                            */

/*==============================================================*/

create table DEPARTMENT 
(

DEPTID               CHAR(8)              not null,

DEPTNAME             VARCHAR2(20),

 DEPTCONTACTNO        NUMBER(10),

BUILDING             VARCHAR2(5),

constraint PK_DEPARTMENT primary key (DEPTID)
);


/*==============================================================*/

/* Table: ENROLS                                                */

/*==============================================================*/

create table ENROLS 
(

STUID                CHAR(8)              not null,

CLASSID              CHAR(8)              not null,

constraint PK_ENROLS primary key (STUID, CLASSID)
);



/*==============================================================*/

/* Table: HAS_PREREQUISITE                                      */

/*==============================================================*/

create table HAS_PREREQUISITE 
(

COURSEID             CHAR(8)              not null,

PREREQUISITEID       CHAR(8)              not null,

constraint PK_HAS_PREREQUISITE primary key (COURSEID, PREREQUISITEID)
);



/*==============================================================*/

/* Table: STAFF                                                 */

/*==============================================================*/

create table STAFF 
(

STAFFID              CHAR(8)              not null,

DEPARTMENTID         CHAR(8)              not null,

STAFFNAME            VARCHAR2(50),

STAFFADDRESS         VARCHAR2(70),

STAFFCONTACTNO       NUMBER(10),

STAFFEMAIL           VARCHAR2(50),

OFFICENO             NUMBER(5),

ROLE                 VARCHAR2(10),

 constraint PK_STAFF primary key (STAFFID)
);


/*==============================================================*/

/* Table: STUDENT                                               */

/*==============================================================*/

create table STUDENT 
(

 STUID                CHAR(8)              not null,

DEGREE               VARCHAR2(10),

MAJOR                VARCHAR2(10),

STU_NAME             VARCHAR2(50),

 STU_ADDRESS          VARCHAR2(70),

CONTACTNO            NUMBER(10),

EMAIL                VARCHAR2(50),

constraint PK_STUDENT primary key (STUID)
);


/*==============================================================*/

/* Table: TEACHING_INFORMATION                                  */

/*==============================================================*/

create table TEACHING_INFORMATION 

(

 STAFFID              CHAR(8)              not null,

COURSEID             CHAR(8)              not null,

SEMESTER             CHAR(2)              not null,

YEAR                 NUMBER(4)            not null,


constraint PK_TEACHING_INFORMATION primary key (STAFFID, COURSEID, SEMESTER, YEAR)
);


/*==============================================================*/

/* Table: TUT_PRAC                                              */

/*==============================================================*/

create table TUT_PRAC 
(

CLASSID              CHAR(8)              not null,

COURSEID             CHAR(8)              not null,

STAFFID              CHAR(8)              not null,

TYPE                 VARCHAR2(5),

DAY                  VARCHAR2(10),

TIME                 DATE,

ROOMID               CHAR(10),

NO_OF_SEATS          NUMBER(2),

constraint PK_TUT_PRAC primary key (CLASSID)
);


alter table ACADEMIC_REC
   add constraint FK_ACADEMIC_RELATIONS_STUDENT foreign key (STUID)
      references STUDENT (STUID);

alter table ACADEMIC_REC
   add constraint FK_ACADEMIC_RELATIONS_COURSE foreign key (COURSEID)
      references COURSE (COURSEID);

alter table COURSE
   add constraint FK_COURSE_OFFERS_DEPARTME foreign key (DEPTID)
      references DEPARTMENT (DEPTID);

alter table ENROLS
   add constraint FK_ENROLS_ENROLS_STUDENT foreign key (STUID)
      references STUDENT (STUID);

alter table ENROLS
   add constraint FK_ENROLS_ENROLS2_TUT_PRAC foreign key (CLASSID)
      references TUT_PRAC (CLASSID);

alter table HAS_PREREQUISITE
   add constraint FK_HAS_PRER_HAS_PRERE_COURSE foreign key (COURSEID)
      references COURSE (COURSEID);

alter table HAS_PREREQUISITE
   add constraint FK_HAS_PRER_HAS_PRERE_COURSE foreign key (PREREQUISITEID)
      references COURSE (COURSEID);

alter table STAFF
   add constraint FK_STAFF_RELATIONS_DEPARTME foreign key (DEPARTMENTID)
      references DEPARTMENT (DEPTID);

alter table TEACHING_INFORMATION
   add constraint FK_TEACHING_RELATIONS_STAFF foreign key (STAFFID)
      references STAFF (STAFFID);

alter table TEACHING_INFORMATION
   add constraint FK_TEACHING_RELATIONS_COURSE foreign key (COURSEID)
      references COURSE (COURSEID);

alter table TUT_PRAC
   add constraint FK_TUT_PRAC_HAS_COURSE foreign key (COURSEID)
      references COURSE (COURSEID);

alter table TUT_PRAC
   add constraint FK_TUT_PRAC_RELATIONS_STAFF foreign key (STAFFID)
      references STAFF (STAFFID);
```

I'm doing this in sql developer and fairly new at using it hope that helps in figuring the solution

Also in teaching information table the staffid and courseid are taken from their parent tables and (semester) and (year) are the attributes of the associative entity between staff & course with many to many cardinalities.

course- *teaching information*-staff

Comment: The error message tells you that the data you're trying to insert has no matching record for the foreign key.

Comment: More specifially, that you don't have a record in `course` with `courseid` ISYS224.

Answer (score 1):

Insert the record in to the Course table first, after that insert into teaching information with same course id that exist in the course table.